# What element for a component's header text

Tags: html, tags, components, element

I have a component that needs header text like this

```
<div class="custom-component">
  <h?>MY COMPONENT HEADER</h?>
  <p>My component content</p>
</div>
```

What element should i use here (in place of `<h?>`)?

If I use `<h3>` or `<h4>` or whatever, i risk breaking the header tree because this component may be used anywhere on the page and could be below an `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` or something else. (Note: [The HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) requires that an `<h3>` not follow an `<h1>` unless there is an `<h2>` in between)

Is there any generic way to define a header element that appropriately defines its content as a header without needing to know beforehand where on the page it will appear in relationship to the other `<h#>` elements?

To clarify, I'm not needing any CSS advice.  I want a semantic HTML header tag that indicates itself as a header (for my component) that doesn't require any foreknowledge of other `<h#>`'s within the document -- i.e. it should be flexible to be used in a variety of places or pages.

Comment: Are the components being rendered dynamically?  If so, can you pass the heading level to the component as required?

Comment: @FrankFurter The header is not rendered dynamically.  But even if it were, that doesn't address the issue.  I am looking for a semantic HTML tag.

Comment: glad you've found an answer - I was going to suggest the section-specific header element but I believe this was eventually deemed to be bad practice, at least where SEO is concerned (I didn't get a chance to research it before answering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question!

The answer is: there is currently no solution using plain HTML. :(

Interestingly, Tim Berners-Lee (founder of the world wide web) actually proposed a generic `<h>` tag [as early as 1991](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-talk/1991SepOct/0003.html)!  But it was never adopted formally or used by any major browsers yet.

If you're using React or Vue, [here is a decent solution that will probably work in most cases](https://medium.com/@Heydon/managing-heading-levels-in-design-systems-18be9a746fa3).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are in a situation where you can benefit from using the BEM conventions.

In BEM you have block, elements and modifiers.

For this specific case I would do this.

```
<div class="custom-component">
  <div class="custom-component__header">MY COMPONENT HEADER</div>
  <div class="custom-component__content">My component content</div>
</div>
```

Just define the styles needed for you to make the component look the way you want to.

But what about you need a specific case where the text needs to be slightly different in the header? Let's say, make it bigger?

```
<div class="custom-component">
  <div class="custom-component__header custom-component__header--big">MY COMPONENT HEADER</div>
  <div class="custom-component__content">My component content</div>
</div>
```

You would just need to write all the css in an appropiate way. I can recommend you to read this documentation:

http://getbem.com/

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  But in my case, I'm wanting semantic HTML tags.  I would have no trouble using CSS to make my component look any way I need it to.  But this approach is not semantic HTML and, as an aside, also does not provide any SEO benefit.